# Simple example from Google Maps Javascript API returns map not found error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I copied the "simple example" at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial into an otherwise blank web page. The only change I made was to substitute my google API key in place of "YOUR_API_KEY" in this line:

```
<script src = 
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer>
</script>
```

When I try to open this page, I get an "Oops, something went wrong message".
The Google Maps Platform API Checker indicates SUCCESS in using the API key, but the INFO part of the message indicates "could not find a visible Google Map within 2 seconds of loading the page."
I also tried with one variation which was to change "https:" in the above-quoted script line to "http:" but the results were the same.
Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

The full code of the page (which is a .html file) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCa5LZ-wqIoBLPk0XcVgMn12fi01iYHS6I&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The line you're talking about doesn't show up. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

When I used the javascript console, I discovered that I was getting a "referrer not authorized" error although I had in fact authorized the API for the URL in question. By searching under that error in Stack Overflow, I discovered several posts about this issue and recommendations to try regenerating the API.  I did that and the problem has been resolved.